# How to get a Random Colour in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, random, colors

I'm creating a program which generates a random car with a random price, year, colour, etc... I know how to randomize the year by using Math.random, but I'm not sure how to get a random colour. I think making an array full of colours and picking a random element from the array, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you can add your colors to an arraylist and simply call Collections.shuffle on it and choose the first one in the newly shuffled list. or you could generate a random number between 0 and the length of your list - 1 and use that index to get a color.

Comment: so if you are choosing which index number to use, could you do a Math.random to choose the index number or will that not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Random` method (import java.util.Random;). Here's an example to make a random company, and you can copy this for the model, color, price, etc.

```
String[] Company = {"Honda", "Toyota", "Ford", "Chevrolet", "Lexus", "Jeep"}// add whatever companies you want here
Random rand = new Random();
int NumberOfAnswers = Company.length;
int pick = rand.nextInt(NumberOfAnswers);
String CompanyChoice = Company[pick];
System.out.println("The company of your car is " + CompanyChoice);
```

Repeat this for the model,  color, or whatever else you want. Note: you do not need to repeat `Random rand = new Random();`, because it only needs to be declared once.

Comment: if you are using this for the numbered options(such as year or price), be sure to change your array to int[] instead of String[].

Comment: Can you include some code in your post please, this will make it easier for me to help you

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Nice and basic too

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most convenient way is making an enum with a method to produce a random element. This way we achieve encapsulation and reuse.

```
public enum Colour {
    Red,
    Orange,
    Green;

    private static final List<Colour> VALUES =
        Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static Colour randomColour()  {
        return VALUES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(VALUES.size()));
    }
}
```